# Liquibase keep applying old changes in changelog after restoring backup

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have Postgis 13 and liquibase 4.17.2 both in docker.

If I run Liquibase with a blank database it will run fine. It will create a database with all the changes in the changelog.xml.

But once I restore a backup and run the liquibase with new changes for some reason it will try and reapply changes in my changelog.xml.

```
<changeSet id="125" author="xxx">
   <validCheckSum>ANY</validCheckSum>
           <sqlFile
        encoding="utf8"
        endDelimiter=";"
        path="125/addfavorite.sql"
        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        splitStatements="true"
        stripComments="false"/>
</changeSet>
```

In the backup of the database is the databasechangelog and the lock version of the table. With all the records of the changes in it. Picture below is the record of the change above.

[image: Record in DB]

```
[{"id":"125","author":"xxx","filename":"../db.bestekchecker.xml","dateexecuted":"2022-11-29T21:46:37.210688","orderexecuted":121,"exectype":"EXECUTED","md5sum":"8:b02e4337396cdf48e077606e7712f4e1","description":"sqlFile","comments":"","tag":null,"liquibase":"4.17.2","contexts":null,"labels":null,"deployment_id":"9754796893"}]
```

I run the liquibase via an bash script. With a loop in it, since I want to apply the same changes to multiple databases and schemas.

```
/liquibase/liquibase  --url $URL --classpath="/liquibase/postgres-jdbc/postgresql-42.2.5.jar"   --driver=org.postgresql.Driver --changelog-file=db.bestekchecker.xml --username=xxxx --password=xxxxx --defaultSchemaName=$schemaname --log-level=warning update -Dschemanaam=$schemaname
```

The log from liquibase gives an error since it can't execute the SQL.

```
[2022-12-08 11:14:12] SEVERE [liquibase.integration] Migration failed for changeset db.bestekchecker.xml::125::XXX:
        Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: column "favorite" of relation "beeldkwaliteit_type_werkzaamheden" already exists [Failed SQL: (0) ALTER TABLE schemaname.beeldkwaliteit_type_werkzaamheden
```

You guys got any clue? Quite frustrating.

Comment: Are you maybe running this from a different directory? In that case the filename might resolve to something different than stored in the database (I can't read that screenshot with the data - it's better to show sample data as formatted text). The unique key that is used to lookup a change consist of `(filename, id, author)`

Comment: I added the record in JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem thanks to [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name).

The migration from local server to docker it changed the filename in the database. For some reason, the local version had ./changelog.xml and the docker named it just changelog.xml.

To combat this I added a new entry to my changelog to check if it has records with ./ and removes it. Problem solved.

Comment: You can also use the `logicalFilePath` attribute in the `<databaseChangeLog>` tag to make sure Liquibase always uses the same filename